# C# pointer and relocation of value type variables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, unsafe

I have written the following unsafe class that wraps a pointer to an int:

```
unsafe class PtrWrapper
{
   public PtrWrapper(ref int val)
   {
       fixed (int* ptr = &val)
       {
           m_ptr = ptr;
       }
   }
   public int Value
   {
       get { return *m_ptr; }
       set { *m_ptr = value; }
   }
   int * m_ptr;
}
```

I've tested it and it seems to work fine, however I've just read the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) on fixed once again and it looks like all operations on a pointer should be done inside the statement:

> Without **fixed**, pointers to movable managed variables would be of
>   little use since garbage collection could relocate the variables
>   unpredictably.

So, is it possible that by the time I call the Value property the pointee is relocated in memory and my pointer points to something else? I know that I have a problem if the pointee goes out of scope, but I will account for it by how I use my class. So I'm asking about *relocating* of a value type variable that has *not* gone out of scope yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible and even probable.

On the heap:

```
class M 
{
    public int i;
    public PtrWrapper w;
    
    public M()
    {
        i = 42;
        w = new PtrWrapper(ref i);
    }
}
    
var m = new M();
var value = m.w.Value; // probably 42

// move m to gen 2
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    GC.Collect();
}

Debug.Assert(GC.GetGeneration(m) == 2);

value = m.w.Value; // probably a random value or AccessViolationException
```

That's why it's called *unsafe*. `fixed` only prevents something from moving while it's within the scope.

On the stack however it should be fine. Only when you go out of scope the variables on the stack would be popped, such as in this case:

```
PtrWrapper M()
{
    var i = 42;
    var w = new PtrWrapper(ref i);
    return w;
}

var w = M();
Console.WriteLine(); // do something else on the stack
var value = w.Value; // some random value
```

Note that captured variables (in lambdas) are really on the heap so you should be careful with those in that scenario.

Comment: Hi Eli, I tried the first example many times but it always gives the same result 42. Did you get a random value when you were running it? I noticed this answer is posted in 2016 and you were probably using an older .Net framework. I'm not sure if it's this reason.